# If the countable infinite product topology is compact, connected, or locally connected, then so is each component

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

For each i∈N, let(Xi,τi) be a topological space. Prove that

(i) if ∏(Xi,τi) is compact, then each (Xi,τi) is compact
(ii) if ∏(Xi,τi) is connected, then each (Xi,τi) is connected

Are we allow to use the projection function pi for each component in the infinite product? If we are allowed to, then we are done since the projection mapping is continuous and connected and compactness are preserved.

(iii) if ∏(Xi,τi) is locally compact, then each (Xi,τi) is locally compact and all but a finite number of (Xi,τi) are compact.

The definition of locally compact is if each point in the set has an open neighborhood that is compact.
Take a point y=(y1,y2,y3,y4.....) There exist a compact open neighborhoud which is of the form (O1,O2,O3,O4....Xi,Xi,Xi,Xi..) because a basic open set is of this form and all but a finite number of i are Xi. Now we can use the projection mapping pi which is a continuous mapping and preserves compactness and we can see that y1 is contained in O1 which is compact. Since x was an arbitrary point all yi contains a compact set in Xi. Now we also note that (O1,O2,O3,O4....Xi,Xi,Xi,Xi..) is a compact set that only contains a finite number of Oi and the rest are Xi implies that all but a finite number of Xi are compact because of the projection mapping.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Be aware that exercise 9.3.1 in the next paragraph is false...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma is that the question about proving a metric is equivalent to another metric? Thanks for the heads up

Comment: Yes that one. You need a weighted sup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the $\pi_i$ are continuous and onto, so $X$ compact implies $\pi_i[X]= X_i$ compact by continuity.

Likewise for connectedness.

For local compactness we also need the $\pi_i$ are open. But that should be well-known to you.

When $f:X \to Y$ is open continuous and onto, and $X$ is locally compact then so is $Y$. We can apply  this to each $\pi_i$ when $X$ is assumed to be locally compact to directly conclude that all $X_i$ must be too.

More precision needed in the netx step:

If $X$ is locally compact it has a compact set $C$ with a non-empty interior.

To say more we go into the product structure: this interior contains a basic open subset $\prod_{i \in I} O_i \subseteq C$. Then if $F \subseteq I$ is the finite subset on which this basic set depends, we have that $X_i = \pi_i[\prod_{i \in I} X_i] \subseteq \pi_i[C] \subseteq X_i$ for all $i \notin F$, so for all but finitely many $i$, $X_i=\pi_i[C]$ is compact by continuity of $\pi_i$.

The reverse is clear: let $F$ be the set of indices of the non-compact $X_i$, which  is finite. For each $x \in X$, we pick a compact neighbourhood $C_i$ of $x_i$ by local compactness and then $\prod_{i \in I} C_i$ is a compact neighbourhood of $x$ (where $C_i = X_i$ for $i \notin F$) by Tychonoff's theorem (and the fact that it by definition contains a basic *open* neighbourhood of $x$).
(That last paragraph is bonus, you only needed the forward direction).